# Need help extracting label from HTML page in C#

Tags: c#, html

I want to load one label's value from a remote HTML page.  I have done that by loading the whole page and than using regex. I found the desired result but this method is very slow I want it to quickly load only labels value not the whole web page. Any suggestions?

This is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = c          client.DownloadString("http://web.archive.org/http://profiles.yahoo.com/italy_");
    var regex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*",
                          RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var s = result;
    foreach (Match email in regex.Matches(s))
    {
        // Console.WriteLine(email.Value);
        label2.Text = email.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: As Nathan said, indeed you have to load the whole page, unless you can create a new server side page that returns you only the requested information through a custom page.

Comment: If you're doing this for multiple pages, then compiling the Regex once and reusing it, rather than for each page processed seems like an obvious optimization...

Answer (score 2):

You must load the whole page - that's the way http requests generally work.

Maybe your regex could be improved?  Not my area of expertise though, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

> I found the desired result but this
>   method is very slow I want it to
>   quickly load only labels value not the
>   whole web page.

Couple of thoughts:

- Archive.org is usually very slow in my experience. My guess is that's your bottleneck.
- No, there is not a way to only make a partial request to a third-party page unless they have a response mechanism capable of returning more specific data (for example, a JSON-enabled web service that returns little snippets of HTML used on the page).
- You will usually have better luck with parsing by loading data into some kind of HTML parser rather than using a regex.